# Issue in sending a string from Android to other device via Bluetooth

Tags: android, string, bluetooth

I am trying to send a string from my Android device to the other device. In my code I am trying to fetch the date and time and storing in a string and then sending that string to the device via Bluetooth.

The issue is when I send the string, some of its characters are missing when received by the other device.

My Code is :

```
private void time() {
    int day = 0;
    Date now = new Date();
    String sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(now);

    switch (sdf) {

        case ("Monday"):
            day = 1;
            break;
        case ("Tuesday"):
            day = 2;
            break;
        case ("Wednesday"):
            day = 3;
            break;
        case ("Thursday"):
            day = 4;
            break;
        case ("Friday"):
            day = 5;
            break;
        case ("Saturday"):
            day = 6;
            break;
        case ("Sunday"):
            day = 7;
            break;
    }

    int mm = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int HH = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int dd = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int MM = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int yy = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100;


        String time2 = "A"+mm+HH+"0"+day+dd+MM+yy+"B";
        sendMessage(time2);
}
```

I send my string by calling sendMessage() function that is given below.

Code :

```
 private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() !=
            com.example.hasani.bluetoothterminal.BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mStartButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.button_default);
        mCalButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.button_default);
        mTestButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.button_default);
        mManButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.button_default);
        mAutoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.button_default);
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();

        while (!mChatService.write(send))
        {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex){
                //Log.d(TAG,"Interrupted Exception");
                //break;
            }
        }

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
    }
}
```

But if I set my string as 
String t = "A000000000000B or "A111111111111B" (length = 14), then the string is received by the other device and I can move to further operations.

Code :

```
private void time() {
    int day = 0;
    Date now = new Date();
    String sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(now);

    switch (sdf) {

        case ("Monday"):
            day = 1;
            break;
        case ("Tuesday"):
            day = 2;
            break;
        case ("Wednesday"):
            day = 3;
            break;
        case ("Thursday"):
            day = 4;
            break;
        case ("Friday"):
            day = 5;
            break;
        case ("Saturday"):
            day = 6;
            break;
        case ("Sunday"):
            day = 7;
            break;
    }

    int mm = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int HH = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int dd = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int MM = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int yy = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100;


        String time2 = "A000000000000B";    //*just to check out assigning this value*//
        sendMessage(time2);
}
```

That is if I am sending string like "A000000000000B" with length=14, it is accepted. But when on computation just like I did above, values are missing from starting position of the string.

Please Help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `String time2 = "A"+mm+HH+"0"+day+dd+MM+yy+"B";` all of your fields are `int` which means that the 3rd minute as string is '3' and not '03'.

If you insist on using `int`, try

```
String min = String.format("%02d", min);
```

Or use SimpleDateFormat which you used earlier to get the day of the week.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mmHH");
dateFormat.setCalendar(cal); 
String mmHH = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: if my minute is suppose 15, the issue still occurs.

Comment: @AkhilNair You should show what time is in your sender and what you receiving.

Comment: suppose I am sending A150304221216B, then I am receiving 150304221216B.

Comment: Ohk its done. I have used your String.format and stored as a string. I have created another handler and called my time() function after a  second delay and then I can receive the string on the other device. Thanks for this  String min = String.format("%02d", min). Take care.

Comment: Here is the link of my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255530/first-three-characters-missing-from-string-when-send-from-android-via-bluetooth